# Jquery code : unexpected token

Tags: jquery, html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if('.huvud li').hover{
        $('ul.hand:not(:animated)',this).slideDown(500);
    }
    else{
        $('ul.sub', this).slideUp(300);
    }
});
```

I am trying to make a code that basically makes a menu slide down when hovering over it, have tried this way, but it says it has some unexpected token, why? 
(im a beginner)

Comment: You're missing parentheses around the `if` condition, and possibly also a `$` before the selector: `if($('.huvud li').hover())`

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` condition is incorrect and missing paranthesis. It should be `if($('.huvud li').hover())`. You need `$('.huvud li')` as `hover()` can only be applied to the `JQuery` object.

Whenever you are working in JavaScript and JQuery you should see the browser console for errors as they help you largely in solving  the error and figuring out what the reason was.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('.huvud li').hover()){
        $('ul.hand:not(:animated)',this).slideDown(500);
    }
    else{
        $('ul.sub', this).slideUp(300);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`.hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) method

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.huvud li').hover(function() {
    $('ul.hand:not(:animated)', this).slideDown(500);
  }, function() {
    $('ul.sub', this).slideUp(300);
  });
});
```

Note this is just a shorthand for

```
$(selector).mouseenter( handlerIn ).mouseleave( handlerOut );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').hover(
       ()=>$('ul',this).slideDown(500)
    ,
       ()=> $('ul', this).slideUp(300)
    )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
hello

</div>
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What If I want to make them separate? Like in your example if I have 2 different ul's and want to make them 2 separate slidedowns/slideups?

Comment: both when hovering of the same element?

Comment: can you add some html of what you mean?